# Routing in Asp.net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to implement CQRS in ASP.NET Core 2.1. I want to separate the command controller from the query controller. For example, I have a controller called ProductController for commands and ProductQueryController for queries. So there are Get methods in ProductQueryController and Post, Put, Delete in the ProductController.

I should redirect a HTTP request when its method property is "GET" to ProductQueryController and when the method is "POST|PUT|DELETE" redirect to ProductController.

1. I'm trying to implement DefaultControllerFactory and IControllerActivator to achieve this indent, but that doesn't solve it.
2. I try to have a Middleware to do this, but that doesn't solve it.

Comment: Are You Sure Add MVC Middleware  to configureServices Method In Startup Class?

Comment: I don't understand the question routing attribute will handle this with out any problems. You could do it with a global route as well but it's a little mor complicated

Comment: yes, of course I add the MVC middleware.

Comment: I don't like to use routing attribute, because I should to add this on by on to all controllers. I should do it by AOP approach, something like  middlewares or ControllerFactory.